# Responsive Wordpress plugin looks strange on different devices

Tags: wordpress, mobile, responsive-design

On my website (talciocdesign.com) I'm having a small problem when I test it on different devices.
-on [desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZn7l.jpg) it looks good,
-but on [iPad Mini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQuOK.jpg), the subtitle text has a different width, almost 100% of the device.
-on iPhone, the text is as it should be, but the image at the top is too small (it should be the same width as the title). I tried to give it a min-width: 250px property- and it works, but it doesn't align it correctly in the center.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this page is built on Bootstrap, a couple of quick fixes below:

The div class col-sm-12 is the reason your subtext is full width I would suggest changing the html classes to fix your issue. For example you could change col-sm-12 to col-sm-8.

On the main image issue on your iPhone I would suggest replacing the class col-xs-8 on  the parent div containing the main image and adding col-centered col-xs-10

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much, it was exactly what I was trying to do.